# how to add mozilla firefox in heroku

Tags: heroku, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, instapy

**>heroku logs -n 10**

```
2021-02-06T18:25:04.446002+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
2021-02-06T18:25:04.446187+00:00 app[worker.1]: response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
2021-02-06T18:25:04.446189+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
2021-02-06T18:25:04.446382+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2021-02-06T18:25:04.446384+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
2021-02-06T18:25:04.446562+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2021-02-06T18:25:04.446600+00:00 app[worker.1]: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
2021-02-06T18:25:04.446605+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-02-06T18:25:04.551198+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-06T18:25:04.629606+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I am trying to use instapy in heroku and encountered this here, looks like there is a problem with the buildpack and path variables
i have installed the following buildpacks to run firefox
http://github.com/buitron/geckodriver-buildpack
http://github.com/buitron/firefox-buildpack

**here are my Config Vars**

Fire
/usr/bin/firefox/

FIREFOX_BIN
/app/vendor/firefox/firefox

GECKODRIVER_PATH
/app/vendor/geckodriver/geckodriver

LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/app/vendor

PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/vendor/